# How to prevent Eclipse from auto-importing packages when pasting code?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Frequently I copy and paste code from my existing code base. Eclipse frequently brings in erroneous import statements that I don't need

example, I copy and paste code into my project package named `com.myproject.utilities` into a file named `twitter_class.java`

and in the java file it adds

`import com.pigmal.android.ex.twitter4j.TwitterConstants;`

and this causes an error `The import cannot be resolved`. Of course it can't why, why did it even attempt to import that part when I didn't even select that for copying

I can imagine places where this is convenient, but it is never convenient for me and it is time consuming to repair so often.

How do I turn this off, in Eclipse, using Eclipse.

Comment: In my experience it only auto-creates imports that are needed to compile the pasted code. Did you ever experience a case where the pasted code would compile without those imports?

Comment: yes, all the time. For instance, in the example I pasted, that was an example project about how to use an SDK. The SDK is already imported into my project as well, and I copied example code that already has all the imports necessary in my project. Yet, eclipse with its "infinite wisdom" decides to import the package name of the other project, despite the fact that I already have the proper libraries added in my project

Comment: I'm confused. There is a difference between "import" statements in source files and adding a library to your project so that the classes in it can be found (and imported). From your statement it's not entirely clear if that's the issue. And then, if the classes you use have different package names in different projects, then Eclipse assumes they are different classes and adds the imports. Was that what you encountered?

Comment: There is no need for eclipse to make that assumption, because the library I have already added to my project already has the pasted classes defined. Eclipse was trying to add new import statements with package names of the other projects, without checking to see if the classes and objects were defined already

Comment: When it automatically imports awt, when I actually am using swt, it can create some extremely confusing situations.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

To turnoff the auto import while pasting

windows **>** preference **>** java **>** editor **>** Typing **>** (Under when pasting) **uncheck update imports**

Comment: Up Up UP! It would have taken over an hour to find that setting. Thank you!

Comment: For Eclipse Neon, you can find this setting under Preferences > Java > Editor > Typing.  Then in this window, find the option When Pasting: Update Imports.  On the Mac, I used the master Preferences dialog by going to the menubar 'Eclipse' item and selecting Preferences... from there.