# How to prevent Eclipse from auto-importing packages?

Tags: java, eclipse

My search first directed me to [this SO question about pasting code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11002239/how-to-prevent-eclipse-from-auto-importing-packages-when-pasting-code). I followed that answer and went about my business, editing other code, etc. A short time later, I was surprised to see that Eclipse had again auto-imported statements in the original file. How can auto-imports be completely turned off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Eclipse: Window > Preferences > Java > Editor > Save Actions > uncheck `Organize Imports`. This globally affects *all* projects in your workspace.

If the annoying auto-import *affects only a few projects*, leave the global `Organize Imports` checked and, from the Preferences window, click on `Configure Project Specific Settings...` and uncheck `Organize Imports`. You can also get there by right-clicking a project, then Properties > Java > Editor > Save Actions > then check `Enable project specific settings` and uncheck `Organize Imports`.

There seems to be another option to stop auto-imports, depending on what is being imported. In the interest of providing a complete answer, I tested this in Eclipse 2019-06 (both global and project-specific settings). In Window > Preferences > Java > Code Style > Organize Imports, remove the entry an auto-import was associated with. For example, if the auto-import is in `com.sun.org.apache.xml...` then remove `com`. Theoretically, if Eclipse isn't managing *any* imports in `com...`, then it shouldn't auto-import `com.sun.org.apache.xml.internal.utils.BoolStack`. However, this setting didn't work to stop the auto-import.